# How to keep vue computed property the same as vuex state and vice versa?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to keep vue computed property the same as vuex state, and vice versa.But it did not achieve my expected result.This is a simple fiddle to show my question.
https://jsfiddle.net/qtttttttttting/Lteoxz9f/22/

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fullName: "hhh hhh"
  },
  mutations: {
    change (state,data) {
      state.fullName = data;
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){return {}},
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
            console.log(333)
            this.fullName="qqq ttt";
            console.log(this.fullName)
    }
  },
    computed: {
        fullName: {
            // getter
            get: function () {
                console.log(111);
                return store.state.fullName;
            },
            // setter
            set: function (newValue) {
                console.log(222);
                store.commit("change", this.fullName);
            }
        }
    },
    watch:{
        fullName(){
            console.log(444);
            store.commit("change", this.fullName);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: If your fiddle does not accurately represent your production environment, please post the production code (ref comment to @gleam's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your computed-setter:
https://jsfiddle.net/0o2cnrvf/

```
        set: function (newValue) {
            console.log(222);
            store.commit("change", newValue);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you .I made a slip in writing. But in my project, in the production environment,  the code does not work.

Comment: try to remove unnecessarry watcher